# Select index to search in using php

Tags: php, sphinx

I have two indexes for sphinx on my webserver for online movies website.
1st is for movies data, and 2d for actors data.
Before i add 2nd index i used that code

```
    public function sphinx_search($str) {
     require_once('../tools/.sphinxapi.php');
     $sphinx = new SphinxClient();
     $sphinx->SetServer("127.0.0.1", 9312);
     $sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
     $sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE);
     $sphinx->SetFieldWeights(['vis_title' => 100, 'title_en' => 5]);
     $result = $sphinx->query($str, '*');

     $ids = [];
     if ($result && isset($result['matches'])) {
       foreach ($result['matches'] as $k=>$v) {
        $ids[] = $k;
       }
     }

     return $ids;
    }
```

Then i used these ids to search in mysql table `movie`

Is it possible to select specific index to search in?
I mean select movies index or actors index in code $sphinx->query($str, '*')

p.s.: sorry about my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '*' in the second param is just which index(es) to search.

```
$sphinx->query($str, 'actors');
```

or

```
$sphinx->query($str, 'movies');
```

or

```
$sphinx->query($str, 'movies, actors');
```

or

```
public function sphinx_search($str, $indexes = '*') {
...
    $sphinx->query($str, $indexes);
...
```